# Will tf.global_variables_initializer() also initialize the iterator for tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I was wondering whether `tf.global_variables_initializer()` also initializes the `iterator` for `tf.data.Dataset`, or I need to initialize the `iterator` separately as:

`iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize the iterator separately.
There is **None** variable feed to `tf.global_variables_initializer()`

[official example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets):

```
max_value = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(max_value)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

# Initialize an iterator over a dataset with 10 elements.
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={max_value: 10})
for i in range(10):
  value = sess.run(next_element)
  assert i == value

# Initialize the same iterator over a dataset with 100 elements.
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={max_value: 100})
for i in range(100):
  value = sess.run(next_element)
  assert i == value
```